# Is our Arabic number system based on a geometric design counting corners?

Tags: math-history, number-systems

The [following writer](https://twitter.com/fahrbier/status/620665850308231168/photo/1) asserts that our system of Arabic numerals is a geometric design where the number of corners corresponds to the number represented:

[image]

My question is: **Is our Arabic number system based on a geometric design counting corners?**

Comment: Short answer: it is not based on that.

Comment: It is not arabic numbers but  indian

Comment: @leox our numerals are from Arabic forms. The Arabic forms are based on earlier Hindi forms.

Comment: @MJD. Yes, so it is Hindi numerals

Comment: The idea is Hindi, but the numeral forms themselves are from Arabic, just as Latin letter forms are based on Greek and not on Phoenician.